# Type arguments in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference between the following two declarations?

```
public<C extends Condition<E>> List<E> search (C condition)

public List<E> search (Condition<E> condition)
```

One difference is obvious: in the first case `C` can be used in the body of `search`. But assumed that `C` would not be used in the body of `search`: is there still any difference?

Comment: Yes, there is - the second one is much easier to read :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Even if `C` is used in the body of `search`, there is no difference in terms of functionality from the perspective of *outside code*, since the second `search` can still just call the first `search` internally

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no useful difference. The distinction could be simplified to the following.

```
<T> void m(T object)

void m(Object object)
```

Although with the first one could call `this.<String>m(42)` and it wouldn't compile - but there's no value to that.

The value of a generic method comes when there is some relationship expressed by its type parameters, for example:

```
<T> T giveItBackToMe(T object) {
    return object;
}

...

String s = giveItBackToMe("asdf");
Integer i = giveItBackToMe(42);
```

Or:

```
<T> void listCopy(List<T> from, List<? super T> to) {
    to.addAll(from);
}

...

List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
listCopy(ints, nums);
```