# Need help understanding a complex generic declaration in java

Tags: java, generics

I am new to generics in java. I came across a method declaration below. Can someone explain in layman terms?

```
public interface SomeService{
   <A, C> C submit(ServiceEnum service, A request, Class<C> responseType);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface declares a generic method with two type variables: `A` and `C`.  The type of `request` is `A` (which could be any object type), and the type variable of the `Class` parameter `responseType` is `C`.  It returns a variable of type `C`.  So, if a `Class<Integer>` is passed as `responseType`, then an `Integer` will be returned.

Comment: So an example invocation would look like this:

Comment: Yeah, there's really no point in declaring `A`. `request` should just be `Object`.

Comment: @PaulBellora Very true.

Comment: So, I'm not sure what this method returns. Does it return a hashmap? With the Key as any object and value as any object? What does the C mean after the type declaration?

Comment: What do you mean by type variables?

Comment: Generic type parameters, A and C, that are inferred from the types of parameters passed into the method.  It would return a `HashMap` if a `Class<HashMap>` (HashMap.class) was passed as `responseType`.

Comment: Wait a minute. So `C` is the return type? And the first angle bracket mess is just input parameters?

Comment: @PaulBellora: whats the difference, why is it better to make it Object rather than some type? thank you

Comment: Yes, `C` is the return type.  The generic type parameters are declared on the method (the `<A, C>`) immediately before the return type.

Comment: @TazMan It's just adding noise to the API, with no benefit. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19935015/697449) for example.

Comment: No, there is no map.  `<A, C>` is just the syntax for declaring two generic type parameters.  It just so happens that the `Map` interface also has two type parameters.  You could have said `<A, C, D>` to declare three type parameters if you really wanted.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This declaration first defines two generic types `A` and `C`. Then it requires that the second parameter is of type `A` and that the third parameter is of type `Class<C>`. The return type of this method will be of type `C`, that type will match the class of the last parameter.

One example of calling this method would be:

```
OrderRequest request = new OrderRequest(...)
Class<OrderConfirmation> responseType = OrderConfirmation.class
OrderConfirmation confirmation = someService.submit(service, request, responseType);
```

Comment: I don't know what this is: Class<OrderConfirmation>.. The Class<C> what is this.

Comment: [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a java class is used for reflection. For example the class `String.class` is of type `Class<String>`, etc

Comment: How can this be used? I don't see how it is required in the code above

Answer (score 0):

**In layman terms**, dealing with generics can be explained this way:

In usual Java programming (without Generics)

You can assign variables.  `int a = 10;`

You can assign objects.    `SomeClass objOfSomeClass = new SomeClass();`

But when you come to Generics, where you specify **type of Objects** (the actual class names)
like `List<String>`, can you substitute `String` with some variable?

The variable **should not** accept usual objects and variables, JUST **classnames**.

Something like  `List<T>`  and then `T = String`.
And please note in this case, we call `T` as **type variable**. (Because it holds class type and not the object itself).
Such assignment of Class names/type is **not** allowed by Java compiler.

**So here is what you do.**

You specify the type variable in `<>` format.

```
interface GeometricShape<T> {
    void drawShape();
    T addShape(T anotherShape);
}
```

Now assume you have classes like `Rectangle`, `Circle`, etc.

So if you give `GeometricShape<Circle>`

then `T addShape(T anotherShape);`  becomes  `Circle addShape(Circle anotherShape);`

In this case, you specified the type variable `T` in the interface, and this `T` is available everywhere inside interface - to all methods.

Suppose I don't want it in full interface, just in one or two methods.
So, you can specify type variables in just only one single method too - by appending `<A, C>` (two type variables here)  **before return type of the method**.

Just like what you have asked.

```
<A, C> C submit(ServiceEnum service, A request, Class<C> responseType);
```

Depending upon what arguments you pass as `request` and `responseType`, your `A` and `C` type variables will automatically be assigned to the class types of your actual arguments.

And in this case, the return type is `C` (depends upon what you actually pass as `responseType`).